# Entity Framework 4 getting primary key ID for inserted record

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using the Entity Framework for inserting a row into my sql database. If I was to be using a stored procedure then I would be able to return the primary key for the record which I had inserted.

Am I able to do return the PK for the last my last record inserted using the Entity Framework?

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Multiple-ways-to-retrieve-Id-of-inserted-entity-using-Entity-framework

Answer (score 41, accepted):

After you have inserted the entity it should have been updated so that the property that maps to the primary key in the database has the new PK value.

Comment: Does that happen on Add or do I have to save changes to the context first before I get a usable ID?

Comment: The changes need to be committed to the database, add just puts it in the context, until you hit the database the PK value will, not be generated.

Comment: Do note that this is not always perfectly reliable due to the SCOPE_IDENTITY bug.

Answer (score 28):

Yes of course you can do this. See example:

```
int id = 0;

using (PC2Entities objectContext = new PC2Entities())
{
   objectContext.ClientContacts.AddObject(clientContact);
   objectContext.SaveChanges();
   id = clientContact.Id;

   transaction.Complete();
}
```

`id` is the PK.

Answer (score -1):

**For Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework (version 6.121 or older)**

If you still do not get the ID after inserting, then add this attribute on the primary key property.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public string ID { get; set; }
```

I had to do this, don't know why, may be because I am using oracle and entity framework is not happy about that.

Edit: I see this answer is down voted, and I know why, because the latest version of ODAP doesn't require you to put the [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]. But this was true for the older versions.