# How can we create a new record with EF when the Primary Key / Identity column is null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

We are using Entity Framework 5 to create a new Answer record in our SQL Server 2012 database.

Here's the Answer Class:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int? AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

}
```

The SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Answer (
   [AnswerId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   ...
   ...
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Answer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AnswerId] ASC)
```

Here is the EF Mapping:

```
public class AnswerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Answer>
{
    public AnswerMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.AnswerId);

        // Identity
        this.Property(t => t.AnswerId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    }
}
```

However when a new Answer is inserted with a null in the AnswerId we still get the following:

The key field 'AnswerId' cannot have a value of null. 
A non-null value is required for the key fields defined on type 'Answer'.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The key field 'AnswerId' cannot have a value of null. A non-null value is required for the key fields defined on type 'Answer'.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.CreateEntityKey(EntitySet entitySet, Object entity)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachSingleObject(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddEntityToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean doAttach)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
       ....
```

So how can I add my POCO class. The only thing I can do is set AnswerId to null as it's a database generated number. But then when I do that EF complains it's null even though I specified it's an identity column to EF.

Comment: And what the question? You can't have `primary key` with null value. If you need this, add other column or remove `primary key`

Comment: Well I am confused here because I assume it's okay to have the primary key as an identity column that's not null. If that's the case then how do I create a POCO Answer class and insert it. I don't know the AnswerId until it is inserted so the only thing I can do is make that null. When I do that then I get the error above :-(

Comment: Don't use `int?` for a primary key.

Comment: Henk - I tried this. However then we have another problem. The Answer object is generated on the front end. AnswerId is set to null and the Answer object comes over as part of a collection in another object. When it hits the controller then it gets converted to a value of zero unless we do int?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't set this key manually (its generating) and when you make `SaveChanges()`, your entity will be updated and `AnswerId` will get his generated PK (it's not your work to generate it or update later).

Comment: Maybe code help to explain it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466224/entity-framework-4-getting-primary-key-id-for-inserted-record

Answer (score 2):

Change your `Answer` class to be like this:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The primary key value will be automatically set by Entity Framework after the database insert.

Do not modify the AnswerId yourself, just leave it be. It will be zero for not yet inserted objects.

Comment: When I set with a value of zero then it seems to go straight to EF and then EF does not even seem to see it as a new answer and does not get a new answer and add it to the question object which contains the answer object.

Comment: @Melina I'm pretty sure this answer is correct. Are you sure you are not setting `AnswerId` to zero (not even to its current value), and are you making sure you are adding your answers to the context instead of attaching them?

Comment: @Melina please add code to the question showing how you add an item.