# MVC with EF - How to update ViewModel after POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am wondering how I can update a `ViewModel` after I done a post on the information.

In my post action I have

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult CreateUpdate(ViewModel viewModel)
{
   repository.InsertOrUpdate(viewModel.Entity);

   repository.Save();

   return View(viewModel);
}
```

Which works and the entity is in the database

However, when I return the information that was saved INCLUDING THE ID Identity key that was created I cannot update this information as the ID comes back to the same post action as 0

I dont particularly want an index page, I would like the post to redirect to the same paqe with the information they have entered (which happens) but when they press submit again, it does an update on the post, not an insert.

How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using generic repository or specific repository. I would amend CreateOrInsert method to return viewModel prior to insert or updated the entity.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/a/6466651/201648 ? Assuming _repository.InsertOrUpdate(...)_ contains a call to _.AddObject(...)_ you should be able to return the inserted/updated model from this method, which you could then assign to _viewModel.Entity_. If returning the model (and assigning) for _repository.InsertOrUpdate(...)_ doesn't give you the required information, could you please post the code for this method?